# Interface callback to fetch info versus parcelable, which is preferred?

Tags: android, interface, callback, parcelable

Performance wise. Which would be ideal? I am doing some calculations in my activity upon startup and the fragments fetch the results relevant to them when they are created.

The reason as to why I did it this way is because Im using a wrapper class and just didnt bother implementing parcelable for it. Does it make a noticable difference?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what you want to acheive :/ parcelable is good for passing objects, Interface is more event oriented. It's up to you to decide which is more apropriate

Comment: @yume117 Id say they both work equally as good in fulfilling their puropose but the interface callbacks will simply occur more often (rotation, when user swipes far enough from the fragment etc). So Im standing in the crossroads between implementing parcelable for this class or just using the interface which ive already implemented.

Comment: i would say just keep it simple, if it's working fine with the interface why use parcable. Plus, knowing it won't be faster or more safe.

Comment: Alrighty. Cheers Yume! :)